# drop-down list autocompletion HTML

Tags: html

I have a drop-down list connected to my database. This list contains geographic features.

When I choose a area to click, it triggers a function that allows to zoom on this area (onclick="zoomToCountry").

This code works:

```
<div class="dropdown">
   <label for="choix_scot"> Territoires : </label>
   <select name="scot" id="scot">
   <?php
      try{
        //Tentative de connexion à la bdd
        $bdd = new PDO('pgsql:host=localhost; dbname=TEST','postgres','');
      }
      catch(Exception $e){
        // En cas d'erreur on affiche un message et on stop tout
        die('Erreur : '.$e->getMessage());
      }

      $requete ='SELECT  "SCOT_2016", St_astext("geom") as "geom_ok" from "GEOMETRIES"."SCOT_GEOFLA_2016" ORDER BY "SCOT_2016" ASC';

      $listScot = $bdd -> query($requete);

      foreach($listScot as $row){
        echo '<option value="'.$row['SCOT_2016'].'" onclick="zoomToCountry(\''.$row['geom_ok'].'\')">'.$row[0].'</option>'; 
      }

      ?>
   </select>    
</div>
```

However, I would like to improve the features of the drop-down list.

For example I would like to give the user the possibility to write within the list (auto-completion).

The code below allows me to write in my list **but** it no longer refers to my function (onclick) which allows me to have a dynamic zoom.

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <label for="choix_scot"> Territoires : </label>
  <input list="scot" type="text" id="choix_scot">
  <datalist id="scot" > 
    <select name="scot" id="scot">
    <?php
      try{
        //Tentative de connexion à la bdd
        $bdd = new PDO('pgsql:host=localhost; dbname=TEST','postgres','');
      }
      catch(Exception $e){
        // En cas d'erreur on affiche un message et on stop tout
        die('Erreur : '.$e->getMessage());
      }

      $requete ='SELECT  "SCOT_2016", St_astext("geom") as "geom_ok" from "GEOMETRIES"."SCOT_GEOFLA_2016" ORDER BY "SCOT_2016" ASC';

      $listScot = $bdd -> query($requete);

      foreach($listScot as $row){
        echo '<option value="'.$row['SCOT_2016'].'" onclick="zoomToCountry(\''.$row['geom_ok'].'\')">'.$row[0].'</option>'; 
      }

      ?>
    </select>
  </datalist>
</div>
```

How can I implement the auto-complete functionality while maintaining the dynamic zoom?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using something like this for dynamic elements?

```
$('document').on('click', '#scot>option', function() {
    zoomToCountry();
});
```

`id` values are also supposed to be unique, but it appears you have the id `scot` declared twice. You need to change that...

Comment: Indeed I had not seen that I had 2 id scot. I just changed that.
On the other hand I do not really know how to use ajax .. I understand the utility but I do not know where to place it